# 'event' is deprecated- what to use instead for React change handlers

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, event-handling, onchange

I am currently building a React app with Material UI.
I'm trying to build a Select component with a dropdown, and as I'm writing the handleChange function, I am getting a warning that my function parameter `event` is deprecated.

I've seen this before when editing other applications with functions that depend on an event variable. Looking online, I've seen recommendations to use `.bind` or `.addEventListener`instead, but I don't totally understand how these work. It also seemingly makes the code way uglier...

I guess I'm just looking for some advice as to how I would implement these alternatives in the case of a MUI Select component. This is what I *want* to write:

```
const handleChange= (event: any) => {
  setState(event.target.value);
};
```

So that I could easily use it in the render function:

```
   <Select
      native
      value={binary}             \\ (state variable)
      onChange={handleChange}    \\ (nice and simple function ref)
      inputProps={{
        name: 'binary',
        id: 'binary-select',
      }}
   >
```

If `event` is deprecated, am I risking a loss of functionality in the future by using it? If I should use these alternative solutions I've seen online instead, how would I apply them in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the actual issue you are facing? From the docs it looks like even the demo (https://material-ui.com/components/selects/#native-select) is using onChange and passing the `event`. Why do you say its deprecated ?

Comment: What exactly is telling you `event` is deprecated? I don't see anything about it being deprecated in the docs (even for v5)

Comment: Hmmm @EmmanuelPonnudurai I guess VSCode was mistaking my event paramter as the GLOBAL event handler, which is deprecated. As you've noted, using event as a parameter is perfectly okay!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess VSCode was mistaking my event paramter as the GLOBAL event handler, which is deprecated. As noted by others' comments, using event as a parameter is perfectly okay!

'Problem' solved.